# Tagged photo in Group not showing up in Timelines

Tags: facebook

I have uploaded several photos directly to a Group page. I have set the photos on "public" and the group is a public group. I have tagged the photos of my friends and myself, but the photos do not show up in my "Photos" nor on my Timeline. My own Timeline and account do not acknowledge that I have been tagged in the group photos.

How do I fix this?

By the way, I have checked my friends' timelines and the photos I've tagged them in are not on their Timelines either.

Answer (score 0):

I've found three source that indicate that what you expect is just not how Facebook photo tagging works.

I don't know if this is the current behavior, but it seems that in 2012, when you asked the question, this was the behavior. And also on 2014-5 when those answers in the sources were given.

**Sources:**

<sup>The answers were given by [Star Contributors](https://www.facebook.com/help/333355536847633).</sup>

- [Tagging Photos in Groups?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1618399961720380)

  > Photos from Groups don't show on Timelines. They may show in their Newsfeed depending upon if they are a member of the Group and follow it.
- [Tag someone and myself in a 'group',but the "tag photo" not showed on timeline.](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=815390941864261)

  > Tags within a group will only show within a group.
- [Why can't I see photos from a public group on my timeline photos of me?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10204495155325634)

  > Groups don't work that way...tagging is a type of notification. You can share the album to your Timeline if you want. But note if the album is deleted from the Group, it's deleted from your Timeline.